# a slightly different string equivalence function in python

Tags: python, string

I have a number of strings that won't match exactly but should be considered equivalent. For example 'Bob' and 'Robert' or 'WWF' and 'World Wrestling Federation'.

To implement the equivalence function, I was going to put all the equivalent strings into tuples and then all the tuples into a list. Then for each input string pair, check if they both exist inside the same tuple and return true if so. Can anyone suggest a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks,
Richard

EDIT: To clarify, the function could receive any two of ('Bob','Robbie','Robert','Roberto') and should return true.

Comment: use a set instead of list, it is faster(maybe frozenset would be even faster.).

Comment: Do you know which one could be the short form? i.e. if `s1` can be "Bob", but `s2` is always "Robert", it might be quickest to look up `s1` in a dictionary, and compare the value you get from that with `s2`.

Comment: @Thomas K, no I don't know what the inputs will be. It could also be more than two strings that are equivalent (eg Bob, Bobby, Robert and Robbie) any two of those should return true

Comment: @Richard: You could map all the alternatives to one form of the name. Then a comparison will always be O(1). I think all the alternatives are either slower or take more memory for little gain.

Comment: You can always use a `dict` to map all the possible combinations (12 in your four Bobs example). I will be faster than searching in a list/tuple/set but will take up a lot more memory and will be less elegant. Depends on what you want to do with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list of equivalence tuples is EQUIVALENCES, you can create a dictionary mapping each string to its equivalences:

```
word_equivs = {}

for equiv in EQUIVALENCES:
    for word in equiv:
        word_equivs[word] = equiv
```

Then you can check if two strings are equivalent by seeing if they map to the same equivalence:

```
def equivalent(s1, s2):
    e1 = word_equivs.get(s1) 
    e2 = word_equivs.get(s2)
    if e1 and e2:
        return e1 == e2
    else:
        return s1 == s2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a dictionary from string to int. 
Then for every set of equivalent strings increment a counter variable counter
may be using a

```
counter  = 0
d = defaultdict(int)
d["WWF"] = d["World Wrestling Federation"] = counter++;
d["Bob"]=d["Marley"]=counter++
```

And when you want to find out equivalence just do

```
if( d[s1]==d[s2] )
```

Comment: You'll need to tweak this: there's no ++ in Python.

Comment: There is no postincrement operator in Python.